# How to find authentication SSH logs for Linux

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-calculation

I am trying to write a query via splunk to find SSH logs used for authentication in Linux. Any ideas as to the query needed to writer to achieve this? I am new to splunk so any information would help.

Here is what I have started but to no avail:

sshd "Invalid user" NOT port NOT "preauth]" | iplocation InvalidSSHIP

Comment: What data sources are you currently ingesting? What index does the data reside in? Do you have permissions to see the data?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you use the Splunk TA for Nix, https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/833/

In it, you will find common inputs and field extractions for SSH event logs, as well as other common *nix formats.

If you follow this TA, you should be able to find the events you are looking for with the following search

```
index=os eventtype=ssh*
```